# "replacement token has no value" when using NuGet replacement tokens with Octopack

Tags: nuget, octopus-deploy, octopack

NuGet allows for a [standard set](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#replacement-tokens) of replacement tokens to be used within a nuspec file nut these tokens don't seem to work when using Octopack, my build fails with the error:

> The replacement token 'id' has no value.

I've done some Googling and found the `OctoPackNuGetProperties` parameter can be pased to MSBuild when creating your Octopack but these seems to be reinventing the wheel when standard NuGet achieves this out of the box.

Is there any way to get Octopack to provide the standard replacement tokens like  `nuget pack` does?

Comment: None as far as I know. We ended up calling nuget directly as a post build step.